# C# ASP.NET Finding the path of a folder WITHIN my project

Tags: c#, path, directory, project

Here is an example scenario;

I have a folder within my solution named either "Images" or "Videos"...
and these particular folders contain files being either Image files or Video files accordingly....

I would like to get a list of the file names within these folders but I cannot seem to understand how to find the path within my project for this...

i.e....

string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path)

I can get the path of directories on the computers drives...but if this is a hosted web application...how do I find the path within the project

string path = Path.GetFullPath("~Videos"); 
or
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName);

these only seem to search the local machine for paths on the C: drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
Server.MapPath("/foldername")
```

for web applications, this will give you the physical path of the folder within your site files. once you have this, you can use

```
Directory.GetFiles(abovePath"); // to get all files in that folder.
```